# Programmatically add Search Box and Search Results webparts in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I have created a custom Search Results page and need to add the Search Box webpart and Search Results webpart to the page programmatically. Has anyone ever accomplished this before?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Web Part Manager class, either SPWebPartManager or SPLimitedWebPartManager. There are a ton of blog posts that explain how to do this in PowerShell and as part of Feature Deployment.

Comment: I've used this class to accomplish adding CEWP and LVWP/CQWP's on the page. I think it was a little different to add Search webparts. I did figure out how to do this. I ended up referencing the classes "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search" and "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" then was able to access the Search Results and Search Box as webparts and add them successfully to the page

Comment: Are you missing a feature dependency? If you browse to the site can you see the web parts in the gallery?

Comment: I wasn't missing a feature dependency. Yes, I can see the web parts in the gallery. I will post a snippet of the code later

Comment: A gogle-doesn't-hurt-like answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet of the code I used

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search;
using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls;



     private static void SetupSearch( SPSite site)
     {
        try
        {
            MyUtil.createPage(site, "/", "Minimal.Search.aspx" , "SearchResults.aspx" , "Search Results" );
            SearchBoxScriptWebPart searchBox = new SearchBoxScriptWebPart ();
            ResultScriptWebPart resultsParts = new ResultScriptWebPart ();
            site.RootWeb.AddWebPartToPage( "Pages", "SearchResults.aspx" , "RightColumn", 0, true , searchBox, PartChromeType.None);
            site.RootWeb.AddWebPartToPage( "Pages", "SearchResults.aspx" , "RightColumn", 1, false , resultsParts, PartChromeType.None);


            foreach ( SPWeb oWeb in site.AllWebs)
            {
                oWeb.AllProperties[ "SRCH_SB_SET_SITE"] = "{\"Inherit\":false,\"ResultsPageAddress\":\"~sitecollection/Pages/SearchResults.aspx\",\"ShowNavigation\":false}" ;
                oWeb.Update();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.LogError( "Error: MyLoggingError for Search " + ex.Message);
        }


     }
```